# Is there an audio amplifier chip or circuit that amplifies certain amplitudes in a signal less or more than other amplitudes?

Tags: amplifier, audio, integrated-circuit, dsp

Like for instance, that would amplify on an exponential curve where the lower amplitudes get the maximum amplification and the highest amplitudes would get no amplification?

Is there an analog chip or circuit that could do this or is it something that would need to be done with DSP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like an audio compressor.

An Audio compressor is a device that passes a low-level signal unchanged but begins to reduce gain when the audio level rises above the threshold value.

The amount of gain reduction is expressed as a ratio: a 2:1 slope allows the output signal to increase by only by 1 dB for every 2 dB increase of input level.

When the slope approaches 10:1 or more, the compressor functions more like a limiter.

There are a lot of nuances with compressors and limiters.  Slope, how the compressor behaves at the threshold point (easy-over or not).

dbx corporation used to make some of the best analog compressors on the market.  The core technology has been spun off into a new company called "THAT Corporation".  [THAT Corporation](http://www.thatcorp.com).  In my humble opinion, they make some of the best audio components available on the planet.

I've used analog compressors and limiters from a number of manufacturers: the dbx units range from good to awesomely-good and the Drawmer units that I've used were even better. [Drawmer](http://www.drawmer.com)

There is now a *lot* of digital implementations out there.  Pretty much every digital console manufacturer has decent compressors and limiters all done in the digital domain.

I'm an old-school audio person and haven't spent all that much time on various digital consoles.  But they all seem pretty good: Yamaha, DigiDesign, Digico, Calrec.

Comment: Thank you both, a compressor does exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Such a circuit is called a **compressor**. There are many analog implementations of such, both with discrete components and with op amps.

Comment: Thank you both, a compressor does exactly what I was looking for.